# Determine if n is a prime.

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers

Let $n$
  be a positive natural number. You know the following facts about $n$
 . Firstly, $n<10^{6}$
 . Moreover, not a single integer $k$
  between $1$
  and $10^{4}$
  divides $n$
 . Does it follows that $n$
  is prime. Explain your answer.

My attempt is: 
Suppose $n$
  is not a prime, that is $n$
  is a composite. This means that $k$
  divides $n$
  such that $k>10^{4}$
 . Now $\frac{n}{k}$
  also divides $n$
  but is smaller than $10^{4}$
 . This means that if $n$
  is prime then $10^{4}<n<10^{6}$ and it would only be divisible by itself. 
 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assumed $n$ being composite and reached a contradiction, namely $\frac{n}{k}<10^2$ dividing $n$. Hence, by the principle of [proof by contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction), $n$ is indeed prime.

Comment: so that means my answer correct?

Comment: @ZainalShariff Yes, it is!